# Initializing a global variable array once for a shader without using CPU code to populate the array

Tags: hlsl

I know I can initialize arrays via code written in C++, etc. to set arrays in a shader. What I want to know is if I can initialize the array in HLSL code instead.

For example:

```
float3 myArray[64] = InitializeFunction();
```

Is this possible?

I've tried calling this type of function in my vertex shader to set values on the array, but I get unrolling errors...

Is there a concept of a function that only runs once per frame for a shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such concept. You must use CPU code to initialize your variables.

Comment: Shader programming is not my area of expertise, but shouldn't it be possible to first use a compute shader to create that array as a raw buffer and then bind that buffer to the vertex shader? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907062/how-can-i-feed-compute-shader-results-into-vertex-shader-w-o-using-a-vertex-buff

Comment: @Philipp sure, but you're still invoking the compute shader from the CPU side, rather than having it automatically invoked as a sort of "initial setup step" of the vertex shader, which is what I read the question to be asking. If it's just about doing the computation on the GPU, even if the CPU still has to invoke each step, then I'd say a compute shader for setup is a good solution worth sharing in an answer.

Comment: Thanks that's what I figured. Too bad, I would love to have had some sort of initialize call so that my shader could be distributed without the coupling to CPU side code. Thanks for the answer.